# php - Changing Table Background Colour With Value Stored in DB Table Field?

Tags: php, background-color

UPDATE. Table id styling :

```
#card {
position:absolute;
border-spacing:0;
border-collapse:collapse;
background-color:#6e97db;
height:720px;
width:100%;
}
```

EDITED

HTML source :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/formbacks.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/slideshow.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Economica:700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Voltaire' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />

<title>Trading Card Generator</title>
<meta name="Description" content="Trading Card Generator - Create Your Own Comics, Predators & Tennis Trading Cards" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="Trading Card Generator, trading card maker, top trumps trading cards" />

<script>
$(function(){
$(document).click(function(){  
$('.messagebox').hide();
});
});
</script>

<style> 
@font-face {
font-family:TCG;
src: url(xirod.ttf);
}

@font-face {
font-family:TCGHEADING;
src: url(GearsOfPeace.ttf);
}

@font-face {
font-family:TCGAUTHOR;
src: url(kenyancoffeerg.ttf);
}

@font-face {
font-family:TCGPN;
src: url(GearsOfPeace.ttf);
}

div {font-family:TCG;}
div {font-family:TCGHEADING;}
div {font-family:TCGAUTHOR;}
div {font-family:TCGPN;}
</style>

</head>

<body id="bodyform">

<p class="header"><a href="index.php">Trading Card Generator</a></p>

<p class="disclaimer">DC vs Marvel&nbsp;<br />
Card Back Face<br />
This is a non profit website.</p>

<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="#">create</a><ul>
<li><a href="backfacecreate.php">back face</a></li>
<li><a href="bcardscreate.php">business</a></li>
<li><a href="comicscreate.php">comics</a></li>
<li><a href="predatorscreate.php">predators</a></li>
<li><a href="tenniscreate.php">tennis</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#">edit</a><ul>
<li><a href="backfaceedit.php">back face</a></li>
<li><a href="bcardsedit.php">business</a></li>
<li><a href="comicsedit.php">comics</a></li>
<li><a href="predatorsedit.php">predators</a></li>
<li><a href="tennisedit.php">tennis</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="register.php">register</a><ul>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#">themes</a><ul>
<li><a href="backfacedisplay.php">back face</a></li>
<li><a href="bcardsdisplay.php">business</a></li>
<li><a href="comicsdisplay.php">comics</a></li>
<li><a href="predatorsdisplay.php">predators</a></li>
<li><a href="tennisdisplay.php">tennis</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="previouscard"></div>

<div class="bouncein">

<table id="card">
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#211e1e"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p class="tcg">Trading Card Generator</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tcgnamecell">DC vs Marvel<br/> Heroes &amp; Villains</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tcgimagecell"><img class="imgsize" alt="" src="uploads/Darkseid.png" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p class="author">Created by M B Mehdi</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="nextcard"></div>
<div class="currentcard">Card 1 of 1</div><br><br>
<div class="currentcard"><a id="carddownload" href="#card" class="downloadbtn">Download</a></div>
</div>

<div id='loader'><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loader"/></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $loading = $('#loader').hide();
$('#carddownload').on('click', function() {
showimage(); 
});
$(document)
.ajaxStart(function () {
$loading.show();
})
.ajaxStop(function () {
$loading.hide();
});
function showimage(){
html2canvas([document.getElementById('card')], {
onrendered: function(canvas)
{
var img = canvas.toDataURL()
$.post("save.php", {data: img}, function (file) {
window.location.href ="downloadbusinesscard.php?path="+ file}); 
}
});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a form that allows users to create a design for the back of a card. Users enter the title, their name, background colour and upload a small image. This is then displayed back inside a table and looks like a large playing card with a small image in the middle and the text above and below.

I use a fetch array to loop through the results and store them as arrays :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tcgbackface JOIN tcgbackfaceimages ON tcgbackface.id = tcgbackfaceimages.id WHERE tcgbackface.username='$user' ORDER BY tcgbackface.id")
or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$theme[]= $row['theme'];
$subheading[]= $row['subheading'];
$author[]= $row['author'];
$bgcolour[]= $row['bgcolour'];
$img_paths[] = $row['path'];
}
```

Then display them back to the user inside a table but when I echo the background colour it doesn't display and the background colour that is set by default in css remains :

```
<table id="card">
<tr>
<td style="background:<?php echo $bgcolour[$i]; ?>">
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p class="tcg">Trading Card Generator</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tcgnamecell"><?php echo $theme[$i]."<br/> ".$subheading[$i];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tcgimagecell"><?php echo '<img class="imgsize" alt="" src="'.$img_paths[$i].'" />'; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p class="author">Created by <?php echo $author[$i];?></p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image: http://thetradingcardgenerator.com/images/Predators_Back.png![Display Background Colour?][1]]

Comment: @MGM do a `print_r($bgcolour);` and post the result here so we can see the content of $bgcolour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
style="background-color:<?php echo $bgcolour[$i]; ?>"
```

**--EDIT--**

I think your `$bgcolour[$i]` might be empty or is not a valid Hex value for a color.

**--EDIT2--**

Try adding a fixe height to your `<td>` element just to see if its height is equal to 0. because it seems empty.

```
style="height:50px;background-color:<?php echo $bgcolour[$i]; ?>;"
```

Comment: @MBM what is the output of $bgcoloeur[$i] ?? could you include an exemple in your post

Comment: var_dump($bgcolour); gives array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "#211e1e" } so it's picking up the value.

Comment: @MGM weird... and are you certain that $i is still in the range of the array?

Comment: Yes as I use the same structure for other fields in other tables and they work fine. If I do this the text HERE is displayed in the hex colour stored in the field but I cannot get it to override the default background colour of the table

<div style="background:<?php echo $bgcolour; ?>">
HERE
</div>

Comment: What is you <td> size?

Comment: Maybe your <td> height equal 0px that is why you dont see anything.

Comment: The card height is set to 720px

Comment: @MBM not the card height the `<td>` element your setting the background color of.

Comment: That did it! But the table id class determines the colour and other elements not the td element. I've resolved it thus <table id="card" style="background-color:<?php echo $bgcolour[$i]; ?>">

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that your CSS sheet is trumping your Style="" code. To be sure, add the following:

```
style="background:<?php echo $bgcolour[$i]; ?> !important"
```

Comment: I already tried that. In fact if I disable the background colour in the css it still doesn't pick up the colour.

Comment: post the output code from your browser for that specific line. there has to be an error in the style=""

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code you've shown here is your actual code, it's invalid.

```
<td style="background:<?php echo $bgcolour[$i]; ?>">
```

has no closing

```
</td>
```

It should be

```
 <td style="background:<?php echo $bgcolour[$i]; ?>"></td>
```

It's not an issue with needing to use !important, because inline styles will always trump a stylesheet. You won't need to use background-color because CSS is smart enough to know.

Are you storing #FFFFFF in the database or just FFFFFF? If you aren't storing the # in the database then you'll need to have that in your output.

Comment: Didn't work. Yes the # is stored. In the bgcolour field in the db I have the following entry #211e1e.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the actual HTML being output to the browser?

Comment: It's as I listed in the opening post excluding navigation. This particular page requires a login but you can get an idea of the HTML by looking at a page that doesn't. The structure is different as there are more elements here but the data is still displayed in a table : http://thetradingcardgenerator.com/predatorsdisplay.php

Comment: The linked page doesn't have any cells that have a style attribute. What we need to see to be able to help you is **exactly** the HTML that your script is outputting.

Comment: I'm not sure how to take a dump of the HTML with live server side code.

Comment: Go to the page that's not behaving how it should. View the source of the page, and edit your question to include the table with the id of card with live values, instead of with your PHP code in it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone for their help. I should have listed the table id style and explained I was using that for styling instead of the td element.

```
<table id="card" style="background-color:<?php echo $bgcolour[$i]; ?>">
```